# Bash script error: integer expression expected

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-substitution

I have a problem with a bash script on raspberry pi:

```
x='gpio -g read 22'

if [ $x -ge 1 ]
then
gpio -g write 23 1
fi
```

The error is `integer expression expected`. Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because you are checking whether the string `gpio -g read 22` is greater than 1. Since `gpio -g read 22` is not a number, you get that error.

You don't explain what you are trying to do but I'm guessing you want to compare the *output* of the `gpio` command. To do that, you need to enclose the command in `$()` or backticks (``` `` ```):

```
x=$(gpio -g read 22)

if [ "$x" -ge 1 ]
then
   gpio -g write 23 1
fi
```

Or, more simply:

```
[ "$(gpio -g read 22)" -ge 1 ] && gpio -g write 23 1
```

The assignment `foo='command'` doesn't run `command`. The variable `foo` takes the value of the *string* `command` and not its output.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer works most of the time but take the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

a='foo: '
b='44494949494'

if [ ${a} -eq ${b} ]
then
   echo "a matches b"
else
   echo "a is different than b"
fi
```

Instead of cleanly echoing one of the above choices, it does the following:

```
./test.sh: line 6: [: foo:: integer expression expected
a is different than b
```

To make the script work as expected (e.g. compare values as strings)
you need to change the comparison to:

```
if [ ${a} = ${b} ]
```